# how to create a branch for a branch in git?

Tags: git, github

There is an branch `xyz` for my master branch. I wanna create a new branch for the branch `xyz`. How can I do this?

Comment: Recommended reading: The Pro Git book: http://progit.org/book/ It's really good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary ways to create branches are:

```
git branch <name> [start-point]
git checkout -b <name> [start-point]
```

The first just creates a branch, while the second creates and checks it out. If the start point is provided (e.g. master) then the branch is created at that point. If it's not, then it's created at whatever you currently have checked out.

In either case, it's really referring to the *commit*; there's no association between branches that's created. That is, `git branch xyz master` doesn't create a branch "for" master, it just creates a branch at the commit master is currently at. If you never merge one back into the other, they'll never know about each other.

Comment: Thanx for this explanation `That is, git branch xyz master doesn't create a branch "for" master, it just creates a branch at the commit master is currently at`

Answer (score 1):

The branch is always created from the current branch. In other words, there’s nothing special here, simply `git checkout -b xyz-branch` while on `xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch new-branch-name-you-want xyz
```